# Error while using web3.py for signature generation to call a smart contract function

Tags: python, solidity

I came across a problem with generating signature for calling a smart contract function.

Here is the solidity function:

```
function checkValidity(
        bytes calldata signature,
        string memory action
    ) public view returns (bool) {
        require(
            ECDSA.recover(
                ECDSA.toEthSignedMessageHash(
                    keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, action))
                ),
                signature
            ) == signer,
            "invalid signature"
        );
        return true;
    }
```

Here is my code for generating this signature using python web3 library:

```
from web3 import Web3


def generate_signature(web3: Web3, sender_address: str, action: str, private_key: str):
    sender_address = Web3.to_checksum_address(sender_address)
    message_hash = Web3.solidity_keccak(['address', 'string'], [sender_address, action])
    signed_message = web3.eth.account.signHash(message_hash, private_key=private_key)
    signature = signed_message.signature
    return signature


public_key = '0x...'
private_key = ''
action = ''
rpc = ''

web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(rpc))

contract = web3.eth.contract(web3.to_checksum_address('0x....'),
                                 abi=json.load(open('abi.json')))
singature = generate_signature(web3, public_key, action, private_key)

result = contract.functions.checkValidity(
        signature,
        action
    ).call()
```

For some reason it doesn't work. Can someone help me out? What am I missing?

I tried multiple functions in web3 python library. Like eth_abi.packed.encode_packed and others. For some reason none of them create a correct signature.